# Centering Roll-Over Images

Tags: css, image, hover, center, rollover

I found the following code on Stack Overflow.

However, the code does not center images. Can some one help me?

The HTML:

```
<div class="photo">
<a href="#">
    <img src="https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/9/9/6/29968995/custom_themes/185017182709687634/files/img/beforeafter/s6.jpg" alt="before" class="before">
    <img src="https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/9/9/6/29968995/custom_themes/185017182709687634/files/img/beforeafter/s1.jpg" alt="after" class="after">
</a>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
    img {
width: 300px;
}
.photo {

position: relative;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
.photo .after {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0; 
display: none;
}
.photo .before:hover + .after, .after:hover {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to achieve that easiest would be flex layout, You need to edit the CSS for photo class, add below lines of code:

```
.photo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; //horizontal align to center
 /* align-items: center*/ -->  this will align it vertically.  
}
```

default direction for flex is row (horizontally) and properties behaves accordingly. if we change the `flex-direction: column`, `justify-content` and `align-items` behave differently depending upon the direction.

**more on flexbox**: 
Best article on CSS flexbox : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox